# Idea complaining about obsolete version of Java on Yosemite but Java 1.8 is installed

Tags: java, intellij-idea, java-8

I have a fresh Yosemite installed mac. From the command prompt I can verify that I have 1.8 installed:

```
╭─user@fox  ~  
╰─$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_25"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_25-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.25-b02, mixed mode)
╭─user@fox  ~  
╰─$ javac -version
javac 1.8.0_25
╭─user@fox  ~  
╰─$ where javac
/usr/bin/javac
╭─user@fox  ~  
╰─$ ls -al /usr/bin/javac
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  75 Jun 18 17:26 /usr/bin/javac -> /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/Current/Commands/javac
╭─user@fox  /usr/libexec
╰─$ /usr/libexec/java_home -V
Matching Java Virtual Machines (4):
    1.8.0_25, x86_64:   "Java SE 8" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home
    1.7.0_07, x86_64:   "Java SE 7" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_07.jdk/Contents/Home
    1.6.0_35-b10-428, x86_64:   "Java SE 6" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0_35-b10-428.jdk/Contents/Home
    1.6.0_35-b10-428, i386: "Java SE 6" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0_35-b10-428.jdk/Contents/Home

/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home
```

When I try to start IntelliJ IDEA 14 I get this error

[image]

clicking update takes me to this page: https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US . Do I need to install something from that page? if so, why? I already have java

Comment: What does `/usr/libexec/java_home -l` give you back?

Comment: @Makoto `-l` gives unrecognized option. I've added the output for `-V` to the question

Comment: Try to go to `IntellIJIDEA/Contents/Info.plist` and change `JVMVersion` to `1.8*`. Anyway if your `JAVA_HOME` points to the correct path, try to set `IDEA_JDK` (it overrides JAVA_HOME in IDEA) too

Comment: value for `JVMVersion` in `info.plist` at the moment is `1.6*,1.7+`. I don't have `JAVA_HOME` set at all. Changing the `info.plist` value to `1.8*` makes IDEA startup

Comment: @MarcoAcierno Please make your comment so the original poster can accept it.

Comment: Done, accept my answer to avoid to left this question without an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to `IntelliJIDEA/Contents/Info.plist` and change `JVMVersion` to `1.8*`.